# Area of quadrangle

Tags: geometry

In the quadrangle $ABCD$, the points $E,F,G,H$ are the midpoints  of respectively $AB, BC, CD, DA$. We know that area $\triangle AHL=a$, $\triangle DIG=b$, $\triangle FJC=c$, $\triangle EBK=d$. Prove that area $IJKL=a+b+c+d$.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Explanation of area notation: Let $[PQRS]$ denote the area of figure $PQRS$.

Label the other areas. Let $[DILH]=e, [GCJI] = f, [FBKJ] = g, [EALK] = h, [IJKL] = i $.

**Hint:** Apply the fact about midpoints.
In particular, $[CEB] + [ADG] = \frac{1}{2} [CAB] +  \frac{1}{2} [ ACD] = \frac{1}{2} [ ABCD] $.
What equation does this give you?

Apply the fact about the other midpoints. What equation does this give you?

Now, conclude that $a+b+c+d = i $. Hence we are done.

Comment: $[CEB]+[ADG]=[HDFB]$ is correct?

Comment: @Marco Yes, because they are both equal to half the area of the quadrilateral. Otherwise, I don't think there is a direct way of seeing that.

Comment: What are $P, Q, R$ and $S$?

Comment: @stuartstevenson dummy variables to explain the area notation.